# Is there a way to detect unwanted modifications in applications?

Tags: android, security

Let's say somebody managed to access my application's source code and injected his code, changed something, or used [DvMap](https://securelist.com/dvmap-the-first-android-malware-with-code-injection/78648/) is it possible to detect this?

EDIT: changed "modifications" with "**unwanted modifications**" in title. Since it's obvious to detect changes especially if you are using VCS.

Comment: Do you use a version control system? For example, if the commit hash in git is the same then the source code is also the same (with extremely high probability)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Use source control**

Every time you make a change to your application's source code, commit / check it in to a source control service like Git, Mercurial or Team Foundation. If anyone changes your code, source control will inform you that you have changes that were not stored in source control - it will show you not only that the code was edited, but what the edits were (what was added, moved, deleted etc).

**2. Use checksums**

Every time you deploy your application to an .apk file, run a checksum on it and save the checksum value to a few locations with the version number. If you like, even write down the first and last 4 characters in the checksum for the version so that if anyone changes the checksum on your website etc to match their *hacked* version, you will know. You can't edit paper

**3. If you have other contributors to your project, heavily document and review each other's code**

This not only prevents bugs and silly mistakes being pushed to live / production builds, but it also stops anything getting passed someone who notices an intentional flaw. In the event someone adds a back door, it will be noticed.

**4. Take basic security measures on your devices**

This is a basic yet overlooked part of security. Essentially, lock your computer when you aren't using it. Use long and secure passwords, or a good password manager like LastPass or KeePass. Don't hand your passwords out to anyone, at all. Don't click on any suspicious links or open files that you don't trust. You get the idea.

Comment: second option seems promising, can you elaborate?

Comment: Checksums take the contents of a file and runs a mathematical hashing algorithm on it. This means that the parts of the contents are used as part of the calculation too - so they can't be reversed like encryption can. Each time you change even a single byte in the file, you dramatically alter the final hash. You can Google 'checksum' for a better definition than what I could give. Is there anything in particular you'd like to know?